# Paying users commission via paypal

Tags: .net, paypal

I'm developing a website  and using paypal method.

i want to send affiliate commission automatically when reached minimum
payment amount set by affiliate.

Now, I want to my sytem auto send payment to a paypal account in a background.

We will store paypal account of system such as email, signature...

I'm a newbie paypal. I use .net to develop this system.

Please give me a advices!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See bellow, you need adaptive payments and there is .net library fro you to start

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments

http://xadaptivepayments.codeplex.com/